# How to check an edittext was enabled?

Tags: android

Hello how can I check if an edittext is enabled
for example

```
editname.enabled=true{
//action 1
}
else{
//action 2
}
```

thanks

Comment: if (editTextField.enabled() == true) something like that ?

Comment: I got canoot resolve methode enabled()

Answer (score 1):

This should help you.

```
if(editname.isEnabled() == true){
//action 1
}
else{
//action 2
}
```

It is recommended to search the question on Google before asking it here.

Answer (score 1):

When the **EditText Enable** its `editname.isEnabled()` its value is `true`.

This is the checking ......................

```
EditText editname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editname);

if (editname.isEnabled()){
    //then the button is enabled.
}
```

enjoy coding..................

Answer (score 0):

You could use this for simplicity

```
if (editname.isEnabled()){
    // editname is enabled
}else{
   // editname is disabled
}
```

Comment: Removed the extra `<br>` tags